# Creating an RGB composite SAR image

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, tiff

I am quite new at Python programming and I need your help. I always do a research for my problem first before posting.

I have SAR dual polarization image (2^16 gray level values) in tiff format. In this tiff image there are two bands. The first band (HH_band) is a horizontal polarization channel and the second one (HV_band) is the vertical polarization channel. I want to create an RGB composite image. For this to happen, I need to layer stack the two channels as follows:

1. get the first band (HH_band)
2. get the second band (HV_band)
3. get the ratio (HH_band/HV_band)

I know that there are many people posting about sometime similar to this (RGB composite image of natural colors). I tried to use `cv2.merge` or `cv2.split` from openCV library but didn't work. I thought it would be relatively easy to create a SAR RGB image in Python (as I have seen a few post about creating RGB image of LANDSAT) but I got stuck in my case.

I would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible way to accomplish the band composition programmatically:

```
import numpy as np

tif = io.imread('dual_polarization_image.tif')

band = {'HH': 0, 'HV': 1}

r = tif[:, :, band['HH']]
g = tif[:, :, band['HV']]

hh = r.astype(np.float64)
hv = g.astype(np.float64)

b = np.divide(hh, hv, out=np.zeros_like(hh), where=hv!=0)

rgb = np.dstack((r, g, b.astype(np.uint16)))
```

Remarks:

- It would be possible to deal with different arrangements of the bands in the TIFF image by simply redefining the values of the dictionary `band`.
- Prior to calculating the band ratio is necessary to convert data to `np.float64`.
- I have taken advantage of the `where` option for [universal functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) to avoid zero division warnings.
- In order for the composition to be possible, the band ratio (blue channel) has to be converted back to the same type (i.e. `np.uint16`) as the original bands (red and green channels).

Comment: That's amazing. Great answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to test without sample images, but you should be able to do this simply at the commandline with **ImageMagick** which is included in most Linux distributions and is available for OSX and Windows.

The command will look like:

```
convert HH.tif HV.tif \( -clone 0 -clone 1 -compose divide -composite \) \
   -combine -auto-level result.png
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I appreciate it